# Python - Cookies & BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, http, cookies, beautifulsoup, cookiejar

I wrote a simple python script that authenticates to a website, gets the cookie write it to a file and do some scrapping at the website. I'm writting the cookie to a file so, I can reuse it and don't need to authenticate my self over and over.

At my personal computer the script works fine. Although when I upload it to my server it refuse to work.

The most strange part is if I upload the cookie created at my personal  computer to the my server it will work fine. Of course, I have some issues at the function that saves the cookie...

As far I as know if I have library issues Python would warm me about it, so I guess my problem is much more complex.

I also tried to run as a root, but no lucky.

What do you think may be causing this stuff?

BTW: All pythons are 2.7

Refer to tags to more infos

Comment: can you give the code snippet you used for authentication?

Comment: It seems you are using different Operating Systems on your pc and the server and there could be a path issue in the part of the code which is writing the cookie in the file.

Comment: You need to check, where the server might have blocked the cookie and so by default its not allowing cookie to be stored and works file when you explicitly put the cookie file